# How to make a non-code block quote in Markdown without tagging every line?

Tags: markdown

Occasionally I'd like to be able to have an indented block quote like this one:

```
>Paragraph 1...

>Paragraphs ...

>Paragraph N...
```

which renders correctly:

> Paragraph 1...
>
> Paragraphs ...
>
> Paragraph N...

But because there are many paragraphs, it's tedious to put the `>` symbol before every single one. Is there a way to do this:

```
<indent (and maybe style) every thing between here>
Paragraph 1...
Paragraphs ...
Paragraph N...
<and here>
```

Comment: No this is not possible. You need to indicate each paragraph is in the blockquote.

Answer (score 1):

You can put 2 or more spaces at the end of a line then return to the next line. That way you only need on >. Not sure about styling in this case, but hopefully this helps

```
> at the end of this line is 2 spaces  
now i'm on a new line, with 2 spaces at the end  
and the next line
```

> at the end of this line is 2 spaces
>       now i'm on a new line, with 2 spaces at the end
>       and the next line

As far as getting an empty line between the two paragraphs, i'm not sure that is possible with a single >.

Comment: Do you need the two spaces for that? I thought the > does this by itself. Unfortunately, without the line break between paragraphs, they won't look like paragraphs and that would defeat the purpose :-(

Answer (score 1):

In Obsidian's markdown, it works to put the `>` marks in front of:

- The first text paragraph
- Each *blank line* thereafter.

I don't know if this works in Markdown generally, or only in Obsidian, but it might help anyone who found this thread (as I did) because they're  working in Obsidian.

This saves a little bit of work at least, namely having to put `>` in front of every text paragraph *and* every blank line.

Example:

```
> First text paragraph.
>
Second text paragraph.
>
Third text paragraph.
```